# query database with python with date range from html form

Tags: javascript, python, html

I have this html code to enter the starting and ending date ranges

```
  <input id="fechaInicio" type="text" 
  <input id="fechaFinal" type="text" 
  <a onclick = "listadoConsulta()" href="#" class="btn"
```

the javascript code

```
  async function listadoConsulta() {
  document.getElementById('fechaInicio').value = date1
  document.getElementById('fechaFinal').value = date2

  var url = URLSERVIDOR + 'listado/consulta'
  var respuesta = await fetch(url, {
    "method": 'GET',
    "headers":{
        "Content-Type": 'application/json'
    }
    }) 
    listado = await respuesta.json();
    var html = ''
    for (registro of listado) {
    
    var row = `<tr>
    <td>${registro.folio}</td>
    <td>${registro.lote}</td>
    <td>${registro.tabla}</td>
    <td>${registro.cajas}</td>
    <td>${registro.peso_neto}</td>
    </tr>`
        html = html + row;
     }
    document.querySelector('#tablaFechas> tbody').outerHTML = html
```

and database query in python

```
    @app.route('/api/listado/consulta')
    @cross_origin()
    def listadoConsulta():
    ejecutarListado = mysql.connection.cursor()
    #date1 = "20220920"
    #date2 = "20220921"
    ejecutarListado.execute('SELECT id, folio, lote, tabla, cajas, peso_neto FROM 
    `registrocorte` WHERE `fecha` BETWEEN ' + date1 +  " AND " + date2 + ';')
    datos = ejecutarListado.fetchall()
    resultadoLista = []
    for fila in datos:
    contenido = {'id': fila[0],
                 'folio': fila[1],
                 'lote': fila[2],
                 'tabla': fila[3],
                 'cajas': fila[4],
                 'peso_neto': fila[5]
                 }
    resultadoLista.append(contenido)
    return jsonify(resultadoLista)
```

It works well if I put the dates directly in the query in python, the question is how can I make it do the query using the dates that I give to the html?

Comment: Using string concatenation as you are is extremely bad practice because you are trusting your inputs. This makes you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks by hackers and could compromise your database or expose data. Please read this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html. Even if you are not using mysql, it shows the general pattern for using parameterized DML and allowing the driver to safely quote and escape your paramters.

Comment: https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection for more information.